# Unexpected encrypted string with AES 256 bit ECB in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to encode a string with AES 256 ECB and padding of zeros with the .Net's System.Security.Cryptography library but the result is not what I expected.

I am testing using [this test case](http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/link/187785bgZd3fF2oBGW/) that matchs [my reciver's code](http://www.area0x33.com/blog/?p=95).

My code looks like this:

```
public static class Util
{
    public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
                             .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                             .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                             .ToArray();
    }

    private static readonly byte[] KEY = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31 };
    private static readonly byte[] IV = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

    public static byte[] Encrypt(string original)
    {
        byte[] encrypted;
        using (AesCryptoServiceProvider aesAlg = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
            aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            aesAlg.KeySize = 256;

            // Create the streams used for encryption.
            using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(KEY, IV))
            using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                {
                    //Write all data to the stream.
                    var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(original);
                    swEncrypt.Write(bytes);
                }
                encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
            }
        }
        return encrypted;
    }
}
```

Then, this is my test case is failling, the result array in hexadecimal is 05212CB5430653FA4BD2253D20353903 not 9798D10A63E4E167122C4C07AF49C3A9.

```
public void TesEncrypt()
{
    var array = Util.Encrypt("text to encrypt");
    var expected = Util.StringToByteArray("9798D10A63E4E167122C4C07AF49C3A9");
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, array);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
//Write all data to the stream.
var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(original);
swEncrypt.Write(bytes);
```

should be

```
//Write all data to the stream.
swEncrypt.Write(original);
```

The StreamWriter already takes care of serializing your string to a byte array.

[Here's a working fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eKz3xV) (I don't have Assert.AreEqual available there, but the first two bytes match your expected output. Oh, and, by the way, [Assert.AreEqual is wrong here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1375166/87698), you should use `CollectionAssert.AreEqual` instead.)

I found this bug by noticing that your original code returned the same output, independent of the input. What happens is that the [TextWriter.Write(object) overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.textwriter.write?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_TextWriter_Write_System_Object_) is called, which calls `ToString` on your byte array (yielding the string `"System.Byte[]"`) and encrypts that string (instead of your input string).

Comment: Great! BTW, I was testing bad my code due to the reference comparation not data comparation.